# How to reduce redundant code during error checking

Tags: c++

> **NOTE:** The restriction is that I cannot use exceptions (the code is eventually compiled with exceptions disabled - not under my control). The project is a real-time 3D graphics application.

I am using my own error class (I had posted a question regarding that not too long ago) which each class uses. Very simple, all it does it records an error during a function call. The function returns that error and it can also be checked by calling `SomeClass->GetLastError()`. If it is `NO_ERROR` (all enums) then we can proceed, although we can chose to ignore it (for example if a particular object does not load, we can ignore it, put an ugly pink box in its place and flag an error). A function `CreateScene()` is called when a `State` is created which then proceeds to call various functions that are responsible for creating the scene. All these functions might potentially return an error. So what I then have is something like this:

```
if (CreateGrid() != NO_ERROR)
{
  mCore->Terimate();
  mLog->Error("\n[FATAL] Initialization Failed, check error log");
  return;
}
if (SomeOtherFunc() != NO_ERROR)
{
  mCore->Terimate();
  mLog->Error("\n[FATAL] Initialization Failed, check error log");
  return;
}
```

The functions called might have different function signatures, so the arguments can be different although the return type is always an integer. I have quite a few calls like the one above so I wrote a `#define` for it which takes in the function as the parameter and is exactly the same as the code above. So now, the above code looks like:

```
CALL_FUNC(CreateGrid());
CALL_FUNC(SomeOtherFunc());
```

The define is undefined once I am done with it. Anyway, this is the only idea I could come up with. Even though it has an *ugly* `#define` the resulting code is clean. Is there a better technique that I should be using here?

Thanks

Comment: I think this stack-exchange [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review") might be of interest to you. If it is show your support and help get it into beta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really don't care which function fails or can determine which one failed by some means other than testing the return value,

```
if (CreateGrid() != NO_ERROR || SomeOtherFunc() != NO_ERROR)
{
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: Bah! Can't believe the solution was so simple! I often tend to over-complicate simple matters. Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for the double reply, but one thing caught my eye. Although in this situation your solution is perfect, what if I cared which function failed (for example to output the name of the function that failed) or if I had to call `->GetLastError()` each time?

Comment: You can break the error handling code into a separate function and call that for each error, passing to it the information it needs.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is "use exceptions" but it sounds like reasons beyond your control are preventing you using the ideal solution.  Here's my alternative: consider `goto` - considered harmful by some, but perfectly legitimate for C-style error checking.  Below is an example, note that all the error handling is in one place, and you know the error code in the error handler, which gains you some of the advantages of exceptions, without actually using exceptions.

```
int ret;

if ((ret = CreateGrid()) != NO_ERROR)
    goto Error;

if ((ret = SomeOtherFunc()) != NO_ERROR)
    goto Error;

// ...

Error:
mCore->Terminate();
mLog->Error("\n[FATAL] Initialization Failed, check error log");
// Note that here, 'ret' stores the value of the last error code.
// This may be useful for further diagnostics at this point, and you
// probably want to log it too.
return;
```

Comment: Great solution! One of the rare but proper uses of goto. I selected James' as the correct answer, but this solution will give me another option down the road. Thanks!